# Performs operations on some observables on trigger observables - RxJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs, frp

I am still trying to wrap my head around using RxJS along with React Native. I am building a login screen with a id TextInput, a password TextInput and a sign in button who all have a separate callback handler attached to them via jsx (hence I can't create an observable using 'fromEvent' API of RxJS).

In componentWillMount, I create a subject for id text change, password text change and the click handler.

```
//In id text change handler
this.idStream.onNext(newId);

//In password text change handler
this.passwordStream.onNext(newPassword);

//In click handler
this.buttonClickStream.onNext(null); //null since value is not important
```

I only want an API request to fire when the button id and password is not an empty string and the button is clicked.

In componentWillMount I tried

```
var subscription = this.buttonClickStream
                       .combineLatest(this.idStream, this.passwordStream, function(click, id, password) {
    return {
         id: id,
         password: password
    };
})
.filter(credentials => {return credentials.id.length > 0 &&
                               credentials.password.length > 0;}
.subscribe(function(credentials) {
    console.log('fire API request with credentials');
});
```

However the problem with this is, since I'm using combineLatest, the api is fired not just on the button click but also every time I change the id or password (provided that they pass the filter). What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use `Rx.withLatestFrom` instead of `combineLatest`. It fires only when the source observable fires and take the last emitted values of the observables you pass as parameter.

Cf. http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom

Comment: Thats the one! Thank you!

Comment: Just as a follow up question, in the example above, is it enough to dispose of the subscription alone? Or should I also 'onComplete' every subject I created?

Comment: not sure, maybe you could raise the lifetime of subjects vs. regular observables as another question.